# Mask A bunch of Image URLs

Tags: php, apache

I'm using a third party API that provides me with a bunch of images. I need to display about 20 to 30 images on a single page, but I don't want anyone who is snooping at the source to know I'm using a third party service for these particular images. How would I go about masking these images so they look like they are coming from my domain name. I would preferably like to know how to do this with PHP or Apache.

P.S Is this bad practice or would I be better of downloading the images and saving them to the cloud?

Thanks

Edit: I took Gordons advice and tried the following and put the following code in my .htaccess, but It's not working for some strange reason.

```
RewriteRule "^/?images(.*)" "https://img-inventory.supplier-domain.com/image/$1" [P]
ProxyPassReverse "/images/" "img-inventory.supplier-domain.com/image/"
```

The following is an example of the supplier URL 
`https://img-inventory.supplier-domain.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:best,t_inv_small/hotel/i/155110/wpmeb5pjxdgse8kvfd87f.jpg`

If anyone can kindly share what I'm doing wrong I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Apache, you can do this without PHP by using either `mod_rewrite` or `mod_proxy`.

Quoting from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html#proxy

> `RewriteRule` provides the `[P]` flag to pass rewritten URIs through `mod_proxy`.
>
> ```
> RewriteRule "^/?images(.*)" "http://imageserver.local/images$1" [P]
> ```
>
> However, in many cases, when there is no actual pattern matching needed, as in the example shown above, the `ProxyPass` directive is a better choice. The example here could be rendered as:
>
> ```
> ProxyPass "/images/" "http://imageserver.local/images/"
> ```
>
> Note that whether you use `RewriteRule` or `ProxyPass`, you'll still need to use the `ProxyPassReverse` directive to catch redirects issued from the back-end server:
>
> ```
> ProxyPassReverse "/images/" "http://imageserver.local/images/"
> ```
>
> You may need to use `RewriteRule` instead when there are other `RewriteRules` in effect in the same scope, as a `RewriteRule` will usually take effect before a `ProxyPass`, and so may preempt what you're trying to accomplish.

If you are using NGINX, you can use the `location` and `proxy_pass` directives:

```
location /some/path/ {
    proxy_pass http://www.example.com/link/;
}
```

See https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/ for details.

IMO, this is a better alternative than using a PHP proxy script because the webserver will handle caching for you. With a PHP script, you will need to handle this yourself.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! I'm trying this approach now. I'll let you know how it works out. I'm most likely going to accept this answer

Comment: @LogicalNonsense try with the ProxyPass instead and make sure to add the protocol to the reverse directive

Answer (score 4):

You can mask them in php file:

```
<img src="image.php?image_id=555" />
```

and image.php like this:

```
<?php
$url = YOUR_URL;
$img_details = getimagesize($url);
header("Content-type: {$img_details['mime']}");
readfile($url);
```

It depends on where you storage URLs to images. But you need to prevent errors, if there is no image by the URL.

Obviously, the better practise is downloading images and show from your own storage.

Comment: Thanks good answer do you know if this would be bad considered bad practice? I'm mostly worried about getting penalized by the search engines.

Comment: The main downside is that you will need to add caching manually

Comment: @LogicalNonsense I'm not sure about search engines. You even may use .htaccess and replace names of images to `images/555.jpg` for example, and `.htaccess` will process them to php-script, maybe it will be better for SE

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that(: Yea I'm going to play it safe and go the .htaccess route do you now  how I would go about doing that?